# how to use "for loop" and "write.csv" at the same time?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I have an array. It has lat,lon,time,and value. Time starts from 1 to 300. Here is part of  array for time=1.

```
myarray[,,1]
     lon                        
    lat -124.5  -123.5  -122.5  -121.5  -120.5  -119.5  -118.5
31.5    0   0   0   0   0   0
32.5    0   0   0   0   0   0
33.5    0   0   0   0   0   0
34.5    0   0   0   0   0   0
35.5    0   0   0   0   0   0
36.5    0   0   0   768.1   0   126.2
37.5    0   0   0.2 0   811 212.1
38.5    0   0   3055    0   243.9   243.7
39.5    0   0   1.5 0.1 3   0
40.5    0.1 16.8    4.3 0.5 2.1 0
41.5    0.2 398.6   0.4 1.2 1.6 0
42.5    0   0.1 0.9 0.1 0.7 0
```

I want to use "write.csv" and "for loop" at the same time to read the data from array for each time step (1 to 300) and store them in individual .csv files which has "i" as index. I used this command but it seems that it doesn't work:

```
for (i in 1:300)    write.csv(myarray[,,i],"myarray.i.csv")
```

Comment: Look at `?paste` for how to construct a string where `i` is evaluated to the current value between 1 and 300 instead of just taken as the letter "i".

Comment: something like `paste("myarray", i, "csv", sep = ".")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple ways of going about this:

```
paste('myarray', i, 'csv', sep = '.')
```

or:

```
sprintf('myarray.%d.csv', i)
```

I prefer the last one.

Comment: @PaulHiemestra, is `sprintf` preferred only because of the cleaner syntax or are there other reasons to it too?

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
n = dim(mydata)[3]

for(i in 1:n) {
  #unpack a 3D array
  mat = mydata[,,i]
  form = sprintf('subject_%s.csv', i)
  write.csv(mat, file = form)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is

```html
for (i in 1:300)  {
write.table(myarray[,,i],file=""myarray.i.csv"",append=TRUE,sep=",",col.names=TRUE,row.names=TRUE) 
  }
```